# ubuntu 14.10 usb boot error

Tags: dual-boot, usb

i have downloaded iso file of ubuntu 14.10 32 bit on my windows 7 system for a dual boot. extracted it on my usb drive. i have made partition correctly on f drive so that it will get it installed along with windows 7. but when i restarted my pc it showed the following error.

syslinux 4.7 edd
no child aborting...
missing parameter in configuration file. keyword path
vesamenu.32 not a com32r image.

i am running ubuntu live on usb. how to install it having windows 7. 
i am new to ubuntu, so plz give any suggestion.

Comment: For me it is not clear what you are asking. Are you just unable to boot from USB (unrelated to what you did on your hard disk), or did you install with the USB-stick and ran in troubles with the first time starting from hard-disk?

Answer (score 1):

## Could be a problem with your iso file \ flash drive.

1. Download ubuntu iso file.
2. Make sure file is good by checking MD5 signature.

   `Download http://www.winmd5.com/`

   `Check if MD5 is matched to: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes`
3. Create a USB bootable flash drive.

   `http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/`

   `(Just select an ISO and the USB flash drive and run it).`
4. Make sure your bios is configure to boot the USB flash drive. Run ubuntu check disk (in the boot menu). If everything is okay install!

## Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

So... I'm not too clear, you can boot from the usb successfuly, and you're now running Ubuntu live? Or you can not boot from the usb and can not run Ubuntu yet?

If you couldn't get the usb to boot, you could try the the same program I used way back when I was using windows to create a bootable Ubuntu usb, very easy, about 2 or 3 clicks if I recall
 http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/
They have some programs that should work for a multi-iso usb too, if you have space for a few iso's look into their YUMI program. I only know how to make them from an already running linux now...